# Esspresso Test for automation

Tags: android

I'm getting below error while running espresso test case for button.in my code i'm using single button with two functionalities ,i'e button with text'Start'function and after completion of start then it should select stop ,same button with 'stop' function i'm using in my code.

Error:Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 644, 972 and precision: 16, 16' on view '(with class name: is "android.widget.Button" and with text: is "START" and with id: 11 (resource name not found))'.

Comment: Test Cases:             onView(allOf(withClassName(is("android.widget.Button")), withText("START"), withId(11))).perform(scrollTo(), click());
 onView(allOf(withClassName(is("android.widget.Button")), withText(startsWith("STOP")), withId(11))).perform(scrollTo(), click());

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding more info as comments.